# extracting organism count with thier corrosponding ID?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, bioinformatics

I have a file with many column like:

```
ID1 XP_026389348.1_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_[Papaver_somniferum]
ID2 XP_026389348.1_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_[Papaver_somniferum]
ID3 XP_026389348.1_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_[Papaver_somniferum]
ID4 XP_026389348.1_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_[Papaver_somniferum]
ID5 XP_026389348.1_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_[Papaver_somniferum]
ID6 XP_022013305.1_60S_ribosomal_protein_L36-2-like_[Helianthus_annuus]
ID7 XP_022033863.1_60S_ribosomal_protein_L36-2-like_[Helianthus_annuus]
ID8 XP_022033864.1_60S_ribosomal_protein_L36-2-like_[Helianthus_annuus]
ID9 XP_022033865.1_60S_ribosomal_protein_L36-2-like_[Helianthus_annuus]
ID10    NP_850400.1_Plant_stearoyl-acyl-carrier-protein_desaturase_family_protein_[Arabidopsis_thaliana]
ID11    XP_015383392.1_60S_ribosomal_protein_L36-3-like_[Citrus_sinensis]
ID12    XP_015383392.1_60S_ribosomal_protein_L36-3-like_[Citrus_sinensis]
ID13    XP_019051818.1_PREDICTED:_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_isoform_X2_[Nelumbo_nucifera]
ID14    XP_019051818.1_PREDICTED:_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_isoform_X2_[Nelumbo_nucifera]
ID15    XP_019051818.1_PREDICTED:_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_isoform_X2_[Nelumbo_nucifera]
ID16    XP_021982111.1_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_[Helianthus_annuus]
ID17    NP_001150213.1_uncharacterized_protein_LOC100283843_[Zea_mays]
ID18    XP_027164486.1_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_[Coffea_eugenioides]
ID19    XP_009419937.1_PREDICTED:_60S_ribosomal_protein_L36-3-like_[Musa_acuminata]
ID20    XP_020267482.1_60S_ribosomal_protein_L36-2-like_[Asparagus_officinalis]
```

i want to extract organism name from 2nd column in [ ] , and count them with their respective IDs like :

```
5   Papaver somniferum       ID1
                             ID2
                             ID3
                             ID4
                             ID5
4   Helianthus annuus        ID6
                             ID7
                             ID8
                             ID9
1   Arabidopsis thaliana     ID10
2   Citrus sinensis          ID11
                             ID12
3   Nelumbo nucifera         ID13
                             ID14
                             ID15
1   Helianthus annuus        ID16
1   Zea mays                 ID17
1   Coffea eugenioides       ID18
1   Musa acuminata           ID19
1   Asparagus officinalis    ID20
```

I have tried something :

```
cat file | cut -f2 | rev |awk -F "[" '{gsub("]", "");print $1 | "rev"}' | sed '/#/d' | sort |uniq -c| sort -nr
```

which gives the output:

```
5   Papaver somniferum
4   Helianthus annuus
1   Arabidopsis thaliana
2   Citrus sinensis
3   Nelumbo nucifera
1   Helianthus annuus
1   Zea mays
1   Coffea eugenioides
1   Musa acuminata
1   Asparagus officinalis
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ datamash -t' ' -g2 count 1 collapse 1 < <(sed 's/^\(ID[0-9]*\).*\[\([^]]*\)\]$/\1 \2/' file) \
   | awk '{ print $2,$1,$3 }' \
   | sed 's/,\(ID[^,]*\)/\n# # \1/g' \
   | column -t \
   | tr '#' ' '
5  Papaver_somniferum     ID1
                          ID2
                          ID3
                          ID4
                          ID5
4  Helianthus_annuus      ID6
                          ID7
                          ID8
                          ID9
1  Arabidopsis_thaliana   ID10
2  Citrus_sinensis        ID11
                          ID12
3  Nelumbo_nucifera       ID13
                          ID14
                          ID15
1  Helianthus_annuus      ID16
1  Zea_mays               ID17
1  Coffea_eugenioides     ID18
1  Musa_acuminata         ID19
1  Asparagus_officinalis  ID20
```

**Step 1**: Extract IDs and organism names with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^\(ID[0-9]*\).*\[\([^]]*\)\]$/\1 \2/' file
ID1 Papaver_somniferum
ID2 Papaver_somniferum
ID3 Papaver_somniferum
ID4 Papaver_somniferum
ID5 Papaver_somniferum
ID6 Helianthus_annuus
ID7 Helianthus_annuus
...
```

**Step 2**:  Feed `sed`'s output into GNU `datamash` and group on second field, count and collapse on first field:

```
$ datamash -t' ' -g2 count 1 collapse 1 < <(sed 's/^\(ID[0-9]*\).*\[\([^]]*\)\]$/\1 \2/' file)
Papaver_somniferum 5 ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4,ID5
Helianthus_annuus 4 ID6,ID7,ID8,ID9
Arabidopsis_thaliana 1 ID10
Citrus_sinensis 2 ID11,ID12
Nelumbo_nucifera 3 ID13,ID14,ID15
Helianthus_annuus 1 ID16
Zea_mays 1 ID17
Coffea_eugenioides 1 ID18
Musa_acuminata 1 ID19
Asparagus_officinalis 1 ID20
```

**Step 3**: Add some formatting to bring the output into the table form:

- `awk '{ print $2,$1,$3 }'` swap columns 2 (count) and 1 (organism name)
- `sed 's/,\(ID[^,]*\)/\n# # \1/g'` replace each comma and ID with newline, two space separated dummy characters `#` and the ID (use GNU `sed`)
- `column -t` format as table
- `tr '#' ' '` replace dummy characters `#` with spaces

Comment: Sorry but it is not working- invalid input: field 2 requested, line 2 has only 1 fields

Comment: I have checked my file using awk to find number of columns: `awk  '{print NF}'`, and it is displaying two column.

Comment: After removing space delimiter from datamash command the error is gone but sed command is not able to fetch organism name, output after `sed` command in one line: `XP_026389348.1_stearoyl-[acyl-carrier-protein]_9-desaturase,_chloroplastic_[Papaver_somniferum]      1     ID1`

Comment: I checked it using cat -e file and it gave output file with `$` unix line endings

Comment: This is the command I am using `datamash -g2 count 1 collapse 1 < <(sed 's/^\(ID[0-9]*\).*\[\([^]]*\)\]$/\1 \2/' see2)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98076/discussion-between-anjali-chaudhary-and-freddy).

Comment: FYI: @AnjaliChaudhary has different IDs in his "real" input file and another small problem. We're trying to fix it via chat.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `awk`, and GNU `column`:

```
awk -F'[][ ]*' '{print ($(NF-1)==n?OFS:$(NF-1)),$1; n=$(NF-1)}' OFS=, file \
 | awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NF==3{line=line RS $0;i++} NF==2{if(line)print i,line; line=$0; i=1}' \
 | column -t -n -s,
```

The first awk command extract and displays the wanted fields in that format:

```
Papaver_somniferum,ID1
,,ID2
,,ID3
...
```

The second awk command builds a new line composed with all fields of the same name and adds its count in front.

At last the column command display the result in 3 columns with the help of `-n` option:

```
5  Papaver_somniferum    ID1
                         ID2
                         ID3
                         ID4
                         ID5
4  Helianthus_annuus     ID6
                         ID7
...
```

Comment: Not displaying results in 3 columns.

Comment: @AnjaliChaudhary Please check the `column` command version. The option `-n` is a Debian GNU/Linux extension possibly not present in your system.

Comment: sorry their are no spaces and also, my file is having tab as a delimiter. here I pasted and modify just to simplify my question.